# What happens between receiving network data on the ethernet port and apache2 doing something?

Tags: apache, networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, hardware

This one is kind of a vague question, because my own understanding is about as vague. I'm interested in what needs to happen for sporadic voltages on the network cables to cause a program running on your computer to do something.

Say I'm running apache2 on my webserver. Somebody triggers the correct sequence of events on their own internet-connected computer, which results in network data arriving at the server. Then what?

My guess is that there is some peripheral component on the motherboard which listens to the data, which then raises an interrupt in the CPU. Somehow, in the interrupt service routine, Linux must ask the apache2 code to do something. Is this correct? If so, would anyone be willing to share a few extra details?

Thanks

Comment: Since you mention voltages and networking in the same sentence, you need to layer your thinking.  That's like the cook asking if you enjoyed the meal, and you talk about beef cells.  There are several perspectives for describing cooked food and networking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll outline what happens from the bottom up, making references to code wherever possible.

### Layer 1 (PHY)

- Ethernet card (NIC) receives and decodes the signal on the wire, and pushes it into a shift register

  - See [Ethernet over twisted-pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair) for the line codes details for each variant of *BASE-T Ethernet
- When full ethernet frame is received, it is placed into a receive  (RX) queue in hardware
- NIC raises an [interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt), using bus-specific mechanism (either [PCI IRQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_PCI#Interrupts) line, or [message-signaled interrupt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Signaled_Interrupts))
- [Interrupt controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_interrupt_controller) ([APIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programmable_Interrupt_Controller)) receives interrupt and directs it to a CPU
- CPU saves running context and switches to interrupt context
- CPU loads interrupt handler vector and begins executing it

IRQs can be shared by multiple devices. The kernel has to figure out which device is actually interrupting. I'll refer to [`e100.c` driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e100.c) as it is implemented in one C file and well-commented.

- Linux kernel looks at all devices that share this IRQ, calling their driver to determine which device actually raised this interrupt. The driver function called is whatever was passed by the driver to `request_irq`. (See `for_each_action_of_desc`() in [`__handle_irq_event_percpu()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/kernel/irq/handle.c#L141)).
- Each driver of devices sharing this IRQ will look at their device's status register to see if they have an interrupt pending
- NIC driver interrupt handler (e.g. [`e100_intr()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e100.c#L2218)) sees the NIC indeed interrupted. It disables the device interrupt (e.g. [`e100_disable_irq()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e100.c#L651)) and schedules a NAPI callback ([`__napi_schedule()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/net/core/dev.c#L4885)). NIC driver "claims" the interrupt by [returning `IRQ_HANDLED`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e100.c#L2243). Interrupt ends.
- Linux kernel NAPI subsystem calls back NIC driver (e.g. [`e100_poll`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e100.c#L2246)) which reads the packet from the NIC RX queue and puts it into a `struct sk_buff` (SKB), and pushes it into the kernel network stack (e.g. [`e100_rx_indicate()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e100.c#L1980)).

The whole TCP/IP stack is implemented in the Linux kernel for performance reasons:

### Layer 2 (MAC)

- Kernel ethernet layer looks at ethernet packet and verifies that it is destined for this machine's MAC address
- Ethernet ethernet layer sees Ethertype == IP, hands it to IP layer

  - Note, the protocol is actually set by the device driver (e.g. in [`e100_indicate()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/drivers/net/ethernet/intel/e100.c#L2046)).

### Layer 3 (IP)

- Kernel IP layer receives packet ([`ip_rcv()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/net/ipv4/ip_input.c#L403))
- Kernel IP layer queues up all IP fragments
- When all IP frags are recieved, it processes the IP packet. It looks at the protocol field and sees that it is TCP, hands it to TCP layer

### Layer 4 (TCP)

- Kernel TCP layer receives packet ([`tcp_v4_rcv()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1544)).
- Kernel TCP layer looks at src/dst IP/port and matches it up with an open TCP connection (socket) ([`tcp_v4_rcv()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c#L1595) calls `__inet_lookup_skb()`).

If it is a SYN packet (new connection):

- TCP will see that there is a *listening* socket open for port 80
- TCP creates a new connection object for this new connection
- Kernel wakes up the task that is sleeping, blocked on an `accept` call - or `select`

If it is not a SYN packet (there is data):

- Kernel queues up the TCP data from this segment on the socket
- Kernel wakes up a task that is asleep, blocked on a `recv` call - or `select` ([`sock_def_readable()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.8/source/net/core/sock.c#L2351))

### Layer 5 (Application - HTTP)

Apache (`httpd`) will wake up, depending on the system call it is blocked on:

- `accept()` returns when a new child connection is available (this is handled with a wrapper called [`apr_socket_accept()`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/2.2.25/os/unix/unixd.c#L523))
- `recv()` returns when a socket has new data, which has been read into a userspace buffer

  - Apache processes the buffer, parsing HTTP protocol strings

## Additional Resources

- [Linux networking stack from the ground up](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/blog/2016/01/linux-networking-stack-from-the-ground-up-part-1/)

Comment: Hi Jonathon! Thank you for accommodating my question so readily.

I need to ask for elaboration on a few things I've never encountered before:
- What do you mean by NIC driver "claims the interrupt"? Does this mean that the kernel calls maybe tens of drivers in the IRQ until one of them returns a success?

- When you say "IP Layer" and "TCP Layer", are these abstract layers in program code? That is, are the two layers implemented in different programs?

- Where exactly are sockets? Does Linux keep a list of ports it is listening to? And what (and where) are these connection objects?

Comment: I've added some more detail. I think you generally "get it" now. I'll come back shortly and add some links to the Linux kernel and Apache source code.

Comment: I've added a bunch of links into the Linux kernel, and also a link to a blog post I discovered which covers the same topic. I hope you find this informative.

Comment: Nice detailed answer.  Assuming the Linux stack supports offloading, it might be worth putting a (*) in there and saying "If offloading is enabled in hardware, the fragment collection step is a no-op".  Also, it's probably worth noting that many modern NICs use DMA, which presumably removes the "copy from HW RX buffer" part (and, I would imagine could result in receiving multiple frames in a single IRQ as well).

Comment: @dgatwood Thank you! Those things did indeed cross my mind, but the answer was already much longer than I'd hoped for. The Linux kernel is a high-performance beast which unfortunately comes at the cost of complexity. Theres simply far, far too much to explain.

Comment: This is incredible. I wish there was some way to for me to give you more upvotes! This post is helping me find a lot of answers I've been looking for.

Comment: Actually, only (obsolete) 10Base-T ethernet uses Manchester encoding. Other, more modern ethernet variants use other encoding methods.

Comment: @RonMaupin Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the answer to be a little more generic there.